# React axios return network error on ios but not on desktops

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, apache

I have a main api host with ssl certificat at https://example.com (PHP 7.4 Symfony 5.1)
And a front-end domain at https://my.example.com (deployed with production build of React)
CORS is configured and cookies are read successfully between domains.

```
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Pagination-Total');
```

Everything works fine on desktop (Windows/Linux). Tested in Google Chrome, Opera and Mozilla Firefox.
XHR requests are sent using axios.
But on ios (12.3.1) i get the following error: Network error - printed in alert using code:

```
 alert(JSON.stringify(e.toJSON()));
```

Axios request example:

```
axios.create({
        baseURL: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST}${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URI_PREFIX}`,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'X-AUTH-TOKEN': token,
            'X-DEVICE-ID': deviceId
        }
    }).get('/user')
            .then((user) => {
              //
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                // alert('and now json');
                // alert(JSON.stringify(e.toJSON()));

                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.setState({isLoading: false})
                }, 2500)
            })
```

[image]

Comment: Can you do remote-debugging through desktop Safari to get the more detailed error message from the console…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating ios to 14.0 version. Probably will be fixed by updating to any version higher than 12.3.1